# using casting in where clause laravel

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

How do I get this to work correctly?

`$listings->where('CAST(number_of_floors as DECIMAL(9,2))', '=', 1);`

Listings is simply

`Listings:where('user_id','=',1)`

Answer (score 7):

Use `DB::raw` like this:

```php
$listings->where(DB::raw('CAST(number_of_floors as DECIMAL(9,2))'), '=', 1);
```

or `whereRaw`:

```php
$listings->whereRaw('CAST(number_of_floors as DECIMAL(9,2)) = ?', [1]);
```